# ASPX editor in ASP.NET MVC warning about a 64-bit assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, 64-bit

I'm using OpenCV via EMGU CV. Since there are separate assemblies for x64 and x86, I'm compiling my entire website solution for x64.

I ran into one problem where the built-in debugging web server freaked out at the x64 binaries, so I started debugging in IIS instead, and that solved most of my problems, except for this one warning that comes up on line 1 of all of my aspx files:

`ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'ImageProcessing' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

The warning message is pretty straightforward given the context -- VS.NET is running in x86 mode, and it's trying to load the x64-only assembly. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to solve it by setting the compile target to Any CPU and the Release compile target to x64.